# Subtract 2 Rows into Column multiple times and link back to header

Tags: sql-server, select, pivot

I have some terrible data that I need to turn into something that means something. I realise this isn't the best way to show I haven't used StackOverflow in ages and I am not sure on syntax.

I have tried to write some queries but really I am not sure where to start on this sort of query so any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

I have a header table which links to a details table. In the details table I have 3 sets of 2 records where I want to get the difference between two columns.

**Header Table**

```
headerId
1
2
```

**Detail Table**

```
detailid|headerId|name|totalElapsedMs
1|1|Request1|100
2|1|Response1|1000
3|1|Request2|1100
4|1|Response2|1800
5|1|Request3|2000
6|1|Response3|2600
```

**Results**

I want to subtract the rows that match each other and then pivot them up to the header row as shown below.

```
headerId|Request1ElapsedMs|Request2ElapsedMs|Request3ElapsedMs
1|900|700|600
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fairly straightforward to use the PIVOT operator on the **Detail** table to get the output you want. Assuming @Detail is your source table, something like:

```
SELECT
    HeaderID
,   COALESCE( [Response1], 0 ) - COALESCE( [Request1], 0 ) AS Request1ElapsedMs
,   COALESCE( [Response2], 0 ) - COALESCE( [Request2], 0 ) AS Request2ElapsedMs
,   COALESCE( [Response3], 0 ) - COALESCE( [Request3], 0 ) AS Request3ElapsedMs

FROM    
    (SELECT HeaderID, Name, TotalElapsedMs FROM @Detail) AS Detail
PIVOT (SUM( TotalElapsedMs ) FOR Name IN ( [Request1], [Response1], [Request2], [Response2], [Request3], [Response3] )) AS PivotedData
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples of Pivot and/or Dynamic Pivot.

The only trick here is to flip the sign, and then aggregate

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([detailid] int,[headerId] int,[name] varchar(50),[totalElapsedMs] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,1,'Request1',100)
,(2,1,'Response1',1000)
,(3,1,'Request2',1100)
,(4,1,'Response2',1800)
,(5,1,'Request3',2000)
,(6,1,'Response3',2600)

Select *
 From  (
        Select HeaderId
              ,Item  = concat('Request',replace(replace(name,'Request',''),'Response',''),'ElapsedMs')
              ,Value = [totalElapsedMs]*IIF(left(name,3)='Res',1,-1)
            From @YourTable
        ) src
 Pivot (sum(Value) for Item in ([Request1ElapsedMs],[Request2ElapsedMs],[Request3ElapsedMs]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
HeaderId    Request1ElapsedMs   Request2ElapsedMs   Request3ElapsedMs
1           900                 700                 600
```

If it helps, the subquery "feeding" the pivot generates

```
HeaderId    Item                Value
1           Request1ElapsedMs   -100
1           Request1ElapsedMs   1000
1           Request2ElapsedMs   -1100
1           Request2ElapsedMs   1800
1           Request3ElapsedMs   -2000
1           Request3ElapsedMs   2600
```